# jQuery .append and .prepend issue

Tags: jquery, html, append, prepend

I have some html:

```
<div class="sample">
  <span>
    Text
  </span>
</div>
```

I want to put an `<a href>` around the Text.

So I have some javascript:

```
$(".sample span").prepend("<a href='http://www.example.com" target='_blank'>");
$(".sample span").append("</a>");
```

But the result is that I get:

```
<div class="sample">
  <span>
    <a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank'></a>
    Text
  </span>
</div>
```

The funny thing is, if I just used 'New Text' instead of the , I get the following:

```
<div class="sample">
  <span>
    New Text
    Text
    New Text
  </span>
</div>
```

Any idea why  changes this?

Comment: try using .wrap() http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `wrapInner` method:

```
$(".sample span")
    .wrapInner("<a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank'></a>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fz3As/

Note that there is a syntax error in your `prepend` method and you cannot pass a `</a>` to those methods for adding a closing tag. This is not the proper usage of those methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wrap()` method

```
$(".sample span").wrap("<a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank'></a>");
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var prepend = "<a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank'>";
var append  = "</a>";
$(".sample span").html(prepend + $(".sample span").html() + append);
```